# Class does not exits - issue on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

This is my error that i receive on the production server:

```
[2020-02-20 14:43:34] main.CRITICAL: Class Mynamespace\Mymodule\Ui\Shipments\PrintAllButton does not exist {"report_id":"28e61f38d5a7de991c74b0bae7bb6efab93aef812fd824e94d0e5238d7b8c157","exception":"[object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class Mynamespace\\Mymodule\\Ui\\Shipments\\PrintAllButton does not exist at /home/..../vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:26)"} []
```

and this my code from the ui component:

```
<settings>
    <buttons>
        <button name="print_all_shipments" class="Mynamespace\Mymodule\Ui\Shipments\PrintAllButton"/>
        <button name="print_last_x_shipments" class="Mynamespace\Mymodule\Ui\Shipments\PrintButton"/>
    </buttons>
    <spinner>shipments_columns</spinner>
    <deps>
        <dep>custom_shipments_grid.custom_grid_data_source</dep>
    </deps>
</settings>
```

and my class is:

```
class PrintAllButton implements ButtonProviderInterface
{
...
    public function getButtonData() : array
    {
...
    }
}
```

I'm 100% sure that my class exits. Especially since on my local is working. If I remove the buttons, I am getting my grid. For some reason I get that error on production. Not sure why ? The production runs a clean install of Magento, no other 3parties module being installed, instead the one that I made :)

Is there a way to debug this ? if Yes, how ?

Comment: Can you post More Code from Namspace @Attila Naghi

Comment: if you think my custom module namespace's name is incorrect.Is not that . It is set correctly :)

Comment: okay, Post Whole-Class code @Attila Naghi

Comment: @Learing_Coder actually you were right !!!!. My issue was an uppercase from my module name :( instead of `Mymodule` I had `MyModule` . I need more coffee!

Comment: Great, You have Achieved @Attila Naghi